# Sulla pronuncia del nome di Natalia Ginzburg

Tags: pronunciation, proper-nouns, name

Ho sempre avuto il dubbio su come pronunciare il nome dell'autrice del *Lessico famigliare*: dovrei dire Natalìa oppure Natàlia?

Per influenza delle mie lingue, che hanno una pronuncia diversa tra di loro di questo nome, ma coincidono nella posizione dell'accento tonico, anche in italiano avevo sempre messo l'accento sulla seconda "a", pronunciando Natàlia, ma non sono sicura se con o senza dittongo in "ia".

Ho chiaramente presente, però, che, in un corso della Scuola ufficiale di lingue di Barcellona, un fiorentino esperto di letteratura ci disse a proposito di Natalia Ginzburg che la pronuncia standard in italiano fosse Natàlia (sulla presenza o no del dittongo non mi ricordo bene).

Il problema è che, in una recente discussione sul *Lessico famigliare*, un'italiana, anche lei esperta di letteratura, ha affermato che gli italiani pronunciano questo nome nella forma Natàlia (mi pare che con dittongo su "ia", ma non ne sono del tutto sicura).

Ho cercato il [nome "Natalia" sul Dizionario d’ortografia e di pronunzia della RAI](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=34425&r=10400), ed ecco quello che sono riuscita a trovare:

[image: dop Natalia]

A dire il vero, la spiegazione del DOP non è del tutto chiara: per qualche ragione a volte si preferisce la pronuncia "alla russa"? E poi la voce "Natalio" con cui si dovrebbe confrontare non si trova.

Come pronunciate o avete sentito pronunciare voi questo nome? Potreste aiutarmi a risolvere il mio dubbio?

Comment: Natalia Aspesi o Ginzburg per esempio si pronuncia con l’accento sulla  i finale. Ma anche Natalia con l’accento sulla seconda a viene usato, (forse di badanti dall’est Europa).

Comment: Anch'io ho sempre sentito e detto “Natalìa Ginzburg”, per il poco che vale. Ma, quel che più conta, con l'accento sulla “i” lo pronunciano il [critico letterario Giulio Ferroni](https://youtu.be/gFc7bRRy2Tw) e soprattutto [il regista Luciano Salce](https://youtu.be/lIICLorqKNE) in presenza della Ginzburg stessa.

Comment: Sul DOP i rimandi ad altre voci sono indicati con una freccetta. Evidentemente con “cfr.” intendono qualcosa come “abbiate presente anche”.

Comment: @DaG: La freccetta credo sia per ascoltare la pronuncia tramite un flash player (non funziona sul mio cellulare né sui miei computer, però). Anche [qui](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=82113) appare "cfr.", ma la voce "badare" si trova sul dizinario.

Comment: Non so se la scelta della pronuncia "alla russa" possa avere a che vedere con l'origine del cognome Ginzburg: infatti era il cognome del marito Leone, di origine russa.

Comment: Giusto, ma non mi riferisco al triangolino per i file audio, ma alle freccette vere e proprie come qui: http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=82114

Comment: Ah, grazie. @DaG: adesso ho capito cosa intendevi con la "freccetta". Mi sono sbagliata: il mio commento precedente non era rivolto a Hachi (l'ho corretto).

Comment: Ok, ho fatto confusione anch'io con chi menzionavo. Scusa, @Hachi!

Comment: Posso suggerire di modificare il titolo della domanda? Come è formulato, sembra riferirsi alla pronuncia del nome "Natalia" in generale mentre mi sembra di capire che la domanda effettiva sia sulla pronuncia del nome della Ginzburg e le due risposte non sono necessariamente coincidenti.

Comment: Fatto, @secan. Grazie del suggerimento!

Comment: E dire che io mi chiedevo come si pronunciasse il cognome, se ginzburg o ghinzburg alla tedesca, come ho sempre fatto io.
Natalia, sia la aspesi che la ginzburg che la estrada, per me ha l'accento sulla A. Marialuisa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Io ho sempre sentito e detto “Natalìa Ginzburg”, ma questo non vorrebbe dire molto.

Quello che direi faccia testo è che lo pronunciano con l'accento sulla “i”:

- il critico letterario [Giulio Ferroni](https://youtu.be/gFc7bRRy2Tw);
- il regista [Luciano Salce](https://youtu.be/lIICLorqKNE) in presenza della Ginzburg stessa;
- la scrittrice [Sandra Petrignani](https://youtu.be/YNJZvdRzeZ0?t=73), autrice di un libro sulla Ginzburg;
- il conduttore [Luigi Silori](https://youtu.be/8AhS_WAqF2k?t=12), ancora una volta alla presenza della scrittrice;
- ma soprattutto [Carlo Ginzburg](https://youtu.be/FVoqbI7SV8A?t=865), grande storico e figlio di Natalia Ginzburg.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao Charo,

Ti rispondo perché purtroppo non ho i 50 punti necessari per aggiungere il commento.

Ti lascio un link inerente ai nomi, in cui oltre alla pronuncia puoi trovare moltissime informazioni.

https://www.behindthename.com/name/natalia

Ad ogni modo, il nome Natalìa è il femminile Natàle. La definizione del dizionario Zingarelli di Natàle è la seguente:

`Natàle`, 25 dicembre, `Natalìa`, 25 dicembre
● Originariamente nome attribuito a persona, maschio (Natale) o femmina (Natalìa, al diminutivo Natalina), nata il giorno di Natale, cioè espressamente nel dīe(m) natāle(m) di Gesù.

In Italia si tende a mettere l'accento sulla `è`. Il nome è molto più diffuso in Spagna ed abbiamo avuto una presentatrice famosa di origini spagnole che tutti conoscono, che ho sempre sentito pronunciare Natàlia Estrada.

[image]

Comment: Che c'entra la Estrada? Natalia Ginzburg e la Aspesi e altre sono famose, e lette persino nelle scuole da decenni prima che nascesse la Estrada...

Comment: E quel sito non mi ispira troppa fiducia: in italiano dà come unica pronuncia quella con l'accento sulla “a” quando nei filmati che indicavo in un commento è chiaro che, almeno per la Ginzburg, la pronuncia è con l'accento sulla “i”.

Comment: E' altrettanto chiara la definizione del dizionario Zingarelli. Secondo te, da noi, se chiediamo a 100 persone se sanno chi è la Ginzburg e chiediamo a 100 persone a caso chi è la Estrada, quale delle due è più nota? Sono convinto che se fai leggere il nome la maggior parte lo pronuncia come la Estrada; poi magari mi sbaglio.

Comment: Ammesso che sia vero (ma dovremmo fare la prova: non possiamo appellarci a statistiche congetturali), che cosa ci dice sulla pronuncia corretta del nome della Ginzburg? Comunque sullo Zingarelli siamo d'accordo.

Comment: Non sono per niente sicura che la pronuncia di "Natale" abbia a che vedere con quella di "Natalia".
Poi, ho appena trovato [Natalìa sull'Enciclopedia Treccani](https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/natalia/): inoltre la posizione dell'accento, non si menziona che abbia a che vedere con il 25 di dicembre. E, scusa la mia ignoranza, non so chi sia Natalia Estrada, ma se è spagnola, mi sembra naturale che il suo nome sia pronunciato "alla spagnola".

Comment: Quale edizione dello Zingarelli stai citando, @GiacomoDB? Non riesco a trovare questa informazione sulla versione che ho sul Kindle.

Comment: Non so che edizione citi Giacomo, ma vedo che quello che riporta coincide con l'attuale edizione, lo Zingarelli 2021 (accessibile solo su abbonamento). Per inciso, la parte enciclopedica ha anche una voce su “Ginzburg, Natalìa”, scritta proprio così. A questo punto mi chiedo gli “esperti” citati da Charo dove abbiano tratto la loro esperienza.

Comment: Io ho la versione digitale 2019, il lemma che ho riportato è ``Natale``. Se volete vi mando lo screenshot. Ad ogni modo nessun dubbio sulla Ginzburg, io avevo inteso che la domanda era generica sul nome Natalìa e non era specifica sulla figura della Ginzburg. Anche sulla mia versione, nella parte enciclopedia c'è la parte che parla della Ginzburg.

Comment: Ho editato la mia risposta ed ho riportato il lemma.

Answer (score 1):

Ciao! Io sono italiana e mi chiamo Natàlia. In Italia entrambe le pronunce (Natàlia e Natalìa) sono possibili.  Nei paesi dell'est e in quelli di lingua spagnola, trovi la pronuncia Natàlia. In ogni caso il nome viene dall'aggettivo latino "natalis", che significa "della nascita/relativo alla nascita" e fa riferimento alla nascita del Signore (Natale appunto). La versione maschile del nome è "Natale" (e non "Natalio").

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta. Nota che, secondo lo Zingarelli, viene dall'aggettivo *natāle* che fa riferimento alla nascita (in generale, non soltanto quella di Gesù).

Comment: Grazie, Natàlia, ma in questa domanda si faceva specifico riferimento alla Ginzburg, più che al nome in generale.

Comment: @Charo: _natalis_ è il nominativo dello stesso aggettivo di cui _natalem_ è l'accusativo; in genere i lessicografi citano quest'ultimo perché se nominativo e accusativo sono diversi spesso l'italiano ha derivato le sue parole dal tema dell'accusativo (per esempio _liber_ / _librum_ > libro oppure _caro_ / _carnem_ > carne).

Comment: Grazie, @DaG: ho completamente dimenticato il pochissimo latino che imparai tantissimi anni fa :(